TypeError: with LangChain, and ChromaDB
i'm having this error using chroma for creating a vectorstores :
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

I run it on my shell, with python 3.10, windows 11
I have the error when using langchain-community and Chroma :
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings

# ...

if os.path.exists(CHROMA_PATH):
    shutil.rmtree(CHROMA_PATH)

embedding_function = OpenAIEmbeddings()
db = Chroma.from_documents(docs, OpenAIEmbeddings(), persist_directory=CHROMA_PATH)
db.persist()

I have the same error using different code, but still chromadb :
import chromadb
chroma_client = chromadb.Client()

collection = chroma_client.create_collection(name="my_collection")

collection.add(
    documents=["This is a document", "This is another document"],
    metadatas=[{"source": "my_source"}, {"source": "my_source"}],
    ids=["id1", "id2"]
)

It feels like the client does not want to work.
This is the details of the error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\file.py", line 42, in <module>
    db = Chroma.from_documents(docs, OpenAIEmbeddings(), persist_directory=CHROMA_PATH)
  File ...
  File ...
  File "C:\...\Python310\lib\pathlib.py", line 576, in _parse_args
    a = os.fspath(a)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

please help me im gonna stop my coding career if i don't resolve this

It shoudl be db = Chroma.from_documents(docs, embedding_function persist_directory=CHROMA_PATH)

You created two copies of the embdedder

But are you sure CHROMA_PATH is a string?

Print each of these to see which one is empty ( NoneType) docs, OpenAIEmbeddings(), CHROMA_PATH
